# coordinate projection

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

I'v got a detail map for an event as PDF an made an openlayers slippy map with Maptiler. I now need to place markers at the position of gps/gsm-trackers, which store their coordinate on a server.

The map's north isn't at top and i need some kind of **formula (projection?)** to translate the gps coordinates to the coordinates of my map.

Is this somehow possible, e.g. via. **2 points where I know the coordinates in both systems**?

I don't expect a finished solution but maybe you can give a hint where to start, I've no idea how to do this.

Example:
GPS 48.26771, 16.36882 (somewhere in Vienna, Austria) in my projection is
0, 0

GPS 48.26673, 16.3696 is
100, 0

Comment: For starters, can you provide an example of your coordinates, which projection are they in currently, and which projectio do you wish them to be in after conversion?

Comment: edited my question, please see example above

Answer (score 3):

The general approach is to georeference the image/PDF, perform a reprojection if necessary (will screw up labels though!) and only then create tiles and overlays.

For georeferencing, you can use QGIS georeferencer for example.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but everything is based on the coordinate system starting with 0,0 on the left top. isn't it possible to translate the coordinates?

Comment: Depending on how the PDF map looks like it **might** be possible to find working transformation settings for scaling, translating and rotating. You can read up on the theory e.g. at http://plone.itc.nl/geometrics/Coordinate%20transformations/coordtrans.html.